# Old version of applet still running in the background in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, applet, processing

Sometime I forget to close my previous applet before I re-compile a new version. So I end up with multiple versions of my old applets hanging around in my dock.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to close these old version before launching the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't such a feature on Eclipse. I've always have to stop the current running instance before starting a new one. Depending on the environment thought, sometimes saving the code files and refreshing the running instance will do the trick (like for example when running a GAE application) but i always better to start with a complete fresh execution to avoid inconsistencies.

Comment: Don't despair. Who knows if someone shocked with my answer gives you a breakthrough alternative :).